Validity of my Nikkah
I wasn't ready to get married. Due to some traumas and my mental health issues I'm uncomfortable with anyone getting close to me or touching me. But my parents never understood. They accepted a proposal for me without my consent. Then they made me get married to him by emotional blackmailing etc.
My main issue is as I didn't want to get married so my father never even showed me my Nikkah form (niqah naama). He filled the form himself and to this day I don't know what is written in my Nikkah form or what information did he fill in. And in the Nikkah ceremony, I've heard that bride or groom has to accept the spouse 3 times saying "I do" (or qubool hai). I was only asked once by my paternal uncle in the presence of witnesses, and I bowed my head down and they said congratulations you're now married sign here and here.
Please answer me regarding these 2 questions, 1st one about not knowing anything about my Nikkah form. Am I responsible to fulfill the conditions of a pact I don't even know of, I never have seen or read. Just because I was asked to sign it?
2nd about accept Nikkah 1 time instead of 3 times?
I've been in this marriage for 6 years almost and these questions keep ticking in my mind. Please reply me asap. جزاک اللہ

We are not a fatwa site. Marriage of a virgin without her consent is disagreed upon, see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/79985/.

Nikah is an agreement, so both sides should be aware of the items accepted upon, the rights and duties. However, I guess if now you read the agreement letter and find it acceptable for you, it would be ok for the previous 6 years as well. I hope that would be the cases, but also consult a scholar.

regarding asking one time or three times, the number 3 is not part of nikah, but maybe cultural. Also I'm not sure but in Iran that they ask the man and woman involved, they are only asking them to agree on the reciter to be their attorney, then making them wife and husband on his own. So saying "I do" is a short form for saying I do accept your attorneyship to represent me.
